# DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table '' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, perl, database-connection

I am sorry if this may be a silly question for you all,but I don't know what to do. I am trying to connect to a local database using perl. When I try to run the command I get below error

```
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: Table 'RegenMedline.user_tables' doesn't exist at Medlineparser.pl line 639.
```

My line 639 is something like this:

```
$main::dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:databasename", 
                       $main::user="username", 
                       $main::password="password",
                       {PrintError => 1,
                        RaiseError => 1,
                        AutoCommit => 1})
                        or die "Can't connect to database: $DBI:errstr\n"; 

my $sth = $main::dbh->prepare("
                SELECT table_name
                FROM user_tables");

$sth->execute();

while (my ($table_name) = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
  print "table_name = $table_name\n";
}
```

I hope this snippet helps and I have put my question in right way. Let me now if I need to give more information. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's kind of strange that MySQL doesn't find `RegenMedline.user_tables`, while you have done something like `SELECT table_name FROM RegenMedline.samples`.

Comment: I am really sorry for that. I have edited the code. I was playing with the code and I forgot to edit it back to user_tables. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: This isn't your problem, but `$table_name` is a list reference, not a scalar. You'll want to say something like `print "table_name = $table_name->[0]\n"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does it work from command line?

```
> mysql -u username -ppassword 

mysql> select * from RegenMedline.user_tables
```

Comment: Well, to be true my database is empty and the command gives me zero results. So, I think it works. I am using this code to parse XML files and populate the database, both working simultaneously. There are no user_tables in my database. I have created the tables and I have used them later in the code. To be true, I got this code from another site which is a open source. I hope I answered your question.

Comment: @sma I sense a similarity between your statement "There are no user_tables in my database" and the error "Table 'RegenMedline.user_tables' doesn't exist".

Comment: If I get it right, you are building the database in your program: when you start the program you have an empty database with no tables ( right? ). You have statements like `CREATE TABLE user_tables` in your program?

Comment: Well, I have already created the tables and user_tables take those values later in the code. I just deleted that thing and it works fine for me now. Thank you all for your help.